# absolute positioning with percentage of an overflow element

Tags: css, overflow, space, percentage, absolute

In the following web page ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4GD8)), I want 10% of spaces in the top and bottom. But when div `#b` overflow, there is no space in the bottom inside the container. What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
#a {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: gray;
}
#b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a">
<div id="b">
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the content in `#b` overflows, you have two options, either invoke a vertical scroll bar or hide the overflow.  How do you want the content to be displayed?

Comment: @Marc As the example, I want to show vertical scroll bar in the div `#a`

Comment: I extended my answer based on your new comments so that the overflowing content triggers a scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a border to the `#b` element,

```
#b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

you will see the top and bottom 10% space: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/r4GD8/1/

However, if the content does not fill up 80% of 200px of height, you will see a larger gap between the text and the bottom of the parent (gray background) container.

You are doing things right, but not visualizing the effect as you expected.

You may be trying to center the content vertically, but that is a different problem.

### Panel with Scrolling of Overflow

If you want `#b` to increase in height proportional to its content, and you want want to retain some white space at the top and the bottom, then you can try:

```
#a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    background: gray;
}

#b {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 160px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

When the `#b` gets taller than 200px, `#a` will show a vertical scrolling bar.

The `min-height` property on `#b` is not strictly necessary unless you are adding a background image or color to `#b`.

You need to specify the lengths for the padding, using percentage values are based on the width of the parent (not the height as you might expect).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/w9qTX/

Comment: 1+ .. Also.. in this instance, you don't need `top` **and** `bottom`.. one or the other works.

Comment: @Marc Percentage values is what I want. Therefore it's not good for using padding.

Comment: You can use % values for padding and margin if you want, but just remember that the computed values will be based on the width of the parent element, not the height.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to `margin-bottom: 10%` and `#b` to `position:relative`

See this [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4GD8/2/)

```
#a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    background: gray;
}

#b {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Comment: margin-bottom is calculated according to the width of the container div `#a`. Thus it is not what i want.

Comment: well, how do you want to calculate these 10% ? You never mentioned it.

Comment: It either going to be 10% of parent container, or 10% of container #b (use padding-bottom for it). Otherwise you need to set fixed number for your CSS bottom rule. Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r4GD8/14/